# 'module' object has no attribute 'PortScanner'

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed python-nmap to create a script.  If I use IDLE and type in the following, it runs fine:

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443')
```

However, if I perform this in Eclipse, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/russ/workspace/ViPyNmap/MyFiles/nmaptest.py", line 2, in <module>
    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PortScanner'
```

I've added the egg file and also the folder to the Eclipse path for the project, with no luck.  I've also restarted Eclipse after doing so, with no luck. I apologize for my inexperience with both Eclipse and Python and appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you got a local file named `nmap.py` in the same directory?

Comment: What does `import nmap; print nmap.__file__` tell you?

Comment: It sounds like the module is in the right spot, so: In eclipse, delete the python folder, and re-add it to force it to reload the modules.

Comment: Thanks Martjin.  That was it.  The file name was nmap.py.  Thank you for the fast response.

Answer (score 36):

You likely installed the package "nmap", not "python-nmap":

[image]

So, just uninstall "nmap" and install "python-nmap":

```
pip uninstall nmap
pip install python-nmap
```

Comment: You should exit the current debug and close the script, reinstall the modules, and then install python-nmap as shown below

`pip uninstall nmap,
pip uninstall python-nmap,
pip install python-nmap`

Answer (score 3):

## 1 analyzing

If you see the source code `nmap.py` at directory `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nmap/`, you will find that there is not class PortScanner.

## 2 solution

### 2.1 method one

You should delete the directory `.../nmap/` with contained files, and install the new the packages `nmap` or by`python setup.py install` at new packages directory.

### 2.2 method two

You also can copy the file `nmap.py` at the new packages to your directory   `.../MyFiles/` with your py file `nmaptest.py`, and run your command `python nmaptest.py`.

***good luck for you !***

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this is happening is because your module that you named nmap.py is now shadowing the intended requests module you are trying to use.

To avoid this, you should rename your module to something else to avoid these situations. Furthermore, chances are you will have generated a nmap.pyc file as well, local to where your nmap.py resides. Make sure you remove that as well after your rename, as the interpreter will still reference that file, re-producing the error.

Example of problem resolution:

renaming file to nmapscan.py, removing nmap.pyc and running again.

Answer (score 2):

Well above answers are working fine in python 2.7, but when we are working in python3 environment following will help to resolve it

*pip uninstall nmap
pip uninstall python-nmap
pip3 install python-nmap*