# AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'

Tags: python, nmap

I am trying to follow an online tutorial "Python For Ethical Hacking". I have the following code:

```
import nmap

nmap1 = nmap.PortScanner()

a = nmap1.map_version()

print(nmap)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nmap_Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    nmap1 = nmap.PortScanner()
AttributeError: module 'nmap' has no attribute 'PortScanner'
```

I have tried uninstalling the module and such but I have had no luck.

Comment: What version of python-nmap are you using? 0.6.1?

Comment: @BjoernRennhak Yea, thats the one I downloaded from https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/

Comment: Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44946218/5046549) is your fix. This was the first google search result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['module' object has no attribute 'PortScanner'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913153/module-object-has-no-attribute-portscanner)

Comment: @BjoernRennhak I compiled as root using "python nmap_Test.py" and I got the error: "ImportError: No module named nmap". However when I compile using "python3 nmap_Test.py" I get the same attribute error as above.

Comment: @ParthSharma I have already looked at those solutions and they did not help.

Comment: Are you sure that you have uninstalled the `nmap` package? What does `dir(nmap)` show? Is `PortScanner` there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173646/discussion-between-parth-sharma-and-felix-doe).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I installed nmap using brew and compiled the program as a root user.

```
brew install nmap
```